# how to change /etc/environment from bash

Tags: bash, permissions, environment-variables

So I messed up. I was experimenting with path environment, and I accidentally edited the `/etc/environemnt` and added `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` and now I stucked on login loop.

I tried to fix my mistake by editing the `/etc/environment` from `ctrl+alt+f3` but I got `Permission denied.

I also tried to use `/bin/su` but again, I got error:

```
bash: kesspipe: command not found
bash: dircolors: command not found
```

Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something like `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment` ?

Comment: @steeldriver I was trying to learn about Linux by self-taught, but I'm not aware of that. It worked like a charm, thanks a lot!